# jQuery Multiple File Upload plugin not working with multiple file type attribute

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery Multiple File Upload plugin from fyneworks. It is not working with multiple file type attribute.

HTML

```
 <input id="bImage" name="data[BusinessImage][image][]" type="file" multiple />
```

JS

```
$('#bImage').MultiFile ({});
```

Kindly recommend some fix.

Comment: what is multiple input tag?

Comment: Ever figure it out? having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `class="multi"` in input tag for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You must add class = multi

```
<input id="bImage" name="data[BusinessImage][image][]" type="file" multiple class="multi" />
```

Comment: Have you included all the related JS files ?

Comment: remove word `multiple ` and try

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers suggest, you need to add class="multi" to invoke the plugin.

Once you do that, the new version of the plugin will support the multiple attribute and perform the validation as you have configured it.

Checkout the new version of the plugin here, with HTML5 support:
http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multifile

And if you want to help us improve the plugin, fork us here:
http://github.com/fyneworks/multifile